# i need to know exactly how to use string.maketrans

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python, please can any one tell me how to use `string.maketrans ()`, with some examples please ?

I find some like:

```
allchars = string.maketrans ('', '')
```

that return the character map, but i couldn't figure out how to use this approach

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After you've created a translation table using `string.maketrans`, you can use the result of that to the `str.translate` method, eg:

```
import string
trans = string.maketrans('ae', 'bx') # a->b and e->x
text = 'abcdef'
print text.translate(trans)
# bbcdxf
```

Comment: Seriously, this should be in the docs.

Comment: @xyres Seriously, it is already been documented in https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans

Comment: @RayLuo I meant the example code should be in the docs.