# I'm trying to check a the characters in a string against a list of tuples. And then swap the character with the other character in the tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

I'm trying to create a cypher where I swap each character in a string 'cab', using the second item in a list of tuples. I plan on adding all the alphabet but this is my test code.  I'm not sure how to check an input string, in this case "cab" against the first item in `tup_list` and then taking that checked list and using the conversions `flip_method`  and `flip_return` below to print out the 'encrypted' string.

```
 def encrypted_list(input= 'cab'):
     tup_list = [('a', '#'),('b', '!'),('c', '@')]
     
     
     '''NEED CODE HERE CHECKING INDIVIDUAL CHARACTERS IN A STING AGAINST tup_list. I THEN NEED TAKE THAT INFORMATION AND UPDATE EACH CHARACTER, USING THE CONVERSTION METHODS BELOW, TO PRINT OUT MY 'ENCRYPTED' STRING.'''
     flip_method = [(sub[1], sub[0]) for sub in input] 
     flip_return = [x[0] for x in flip_method]
     print (flip_return)
```

I trie using :

```
x = INPUT
Output = []
for i in Input:
    if x in i:
        Output.append(i)
```

and it just keeps coming back as none

Comment: Please edit the question and put the code in a code block, not quotation, so the formatting will be correct. Your code is currently unreadable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: so the output would be `@#!` ?

Comment: I recommend using a dictionary rather than a list of tuples.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `[(sub[1], sub[0]) for sub in input]`? `sub` is a single character, so there's no `sub[1]`.

Comment: `for i in Input:` You never assigned the variable `Input`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i need to know exactly how to use string.maketrans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815696/i-need-to-know-exactly-how-to-use-string-maketrans)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is only a mapping from the your input alphabet to the "encrypted" alphabet

1. You can do it manually using a dictionnary

   ```
   MAPPING = {'a': '#', 'b': '!', 'c': '@'}    

   def encrypted_list(value: str):
       return "".join(MAPPING[letter] for letter in value)

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       print(encrypted_list("abc"))  # '#!@'
       print(encrypted_list("cab"))  # '@#!'
   ```
2. You can do it with str.translate

   ```
   MAPPING = str.maketrans({'a': '#', 'b': '!', 'c': '@'})

   def encrypted_list(value: str):
       return value.translate(MAPPING)
   ```

---

To decrypt just create the inverse mapping

```
# with simple dict
DEV_MAPPING = {val: key for key, val in MAPPING.items()}

# with translate
MAPPING = {'a': '#', 'b': '!', 'c': '@'}
ENC_MAPPING = str.maketrans(MAPPING)
DEC_MAPPING = str.maketrans({val: key for key, val in MAPPING.items()})
```

Comment: Is there a way to reverse the map so I could also "decrypt" the string. I.E. @#! >>cab? Thank you!

Comment: @NicholasBoatwright just reverse the dict, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

If you use a dictionary rather than a list of tuples you will gain efficiency and also a very simple mechanism for decoding as well as encoding.

Something like this:

```
ENCODE = {
    'a': '#',
    'b': '!',
    'c': '@'
}

DECODE = {v: k for k, v in ENCODE.items()}

def encode(word):
    return ''.join([ENCODE[c] for c in word])

def decode(word):
    return ''.join([DECODE[c] for c in word])


ew = encode('cab')
print(ew)
dw = decode(ew)
print(dw)
```

**Output:**

```
@#!
cab
```

**Note:**

This may not be robust as there are no checks to ensure that the characters in the input string have corresponding keys in either of the dictionaries